# Tensorflow DNNClassifier error: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use the tf.estimator.DNNClassifier to predict the monthly price for a dataset. However when running the program I am getting an error with the DNNClassifier stating that the labels is not <= n_classes -1.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Labels must <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (dnn/head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[51][58][50]...] [y (dnn/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
```

It seems as if it is not recognizing my feature columns in the DNN classifier. The following code is what I am running.

```js
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


df = pd.read_csv('./csv/lmtensordata.csv')


deep_feat = df.drop(columns=['monthly_price'], axis=1)
deep_label = df['monthly_price']

df.info()
df.head()

numerical_columns = [col for col in df.columns if (df[col].dtype=='int64' or df[col].dtype=='float64')]


categorical_columns = [col for col in deep_feat.columns if len(deep_feat[col].unique()) == 2 or deep_feat[col].dtype == 'O']

continuous_columns = [col for col in deep_feat.columns if len(deep_feat[col].unique()) > 2 and (deep_feat[col].dtype == 'int64' or deep_feat[col].dtype=='float64')]



# making a train test split
X_T, X_t, y_T, y_t = train_test_split(deep_feat, deep_label, test_size=0.3)

cols_to_scale = continuous_columns[:]

# scaling the listed columns
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_T.loc[:,cols_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(X_T.loc[:,cols_to_scale])
X_t.loc[:,cols_to_scale] = scaler.fit_transform(X_t.loc[:,cols_to_scale])


continuous_feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=col) for col in continuous_columns]

feat_cols = continuous_feat_cols


input_fun = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(X_T,y_T,batch_size=50,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)
pred_input_fun = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(X_t,batch_size=50,shuffle=False)

DNN_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,10,10], feature_columns=feat_cols, n_classes=2)

DNN_model.train(input_fn=input_fun, steps=5000)

predictions = DNN_model.predict(pred_input_fun)

res_pred = list(predictions)
print(res_pred[0])
```

When I print out my feat_cols this is what I am getting.

```html
[  
   _NumericColumn(key='car_year',
   shape=(1,),
   default_value=None,
   dtype=tf.float32,
   normalizer_fn=None),
   
   _NumericColumn(key='make_model_bucket',
   shape=(1,
   ),
   default_value=None,
   dtype=tf.float32,
   normalizer_fn=None),
   
   _NumericColumn(key='mileage',
   shape=(1,
   ),
   default_value=None,
   dtype=tf.float32,
   normalizer_fn=None),
   
   _NumericColumn(key='years_licensed_bucket',
   shape=(1,
   ),
   default_value=None,
   dtype=tf.float32,
   normalizer_fn=None),
   
   _NumericColumn(key='zip_bucket',
   shape=(1,
   ),
   default_value=None,
   dtype=tf.float32,
   normalizer_fn=None)
]
```

Here is also the df.head() output of the dataset I am working with.

```html
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 33588 entries, 0 to 33587
Data columns (total 6 columns):
car_year                 33588 non-null int64
make_model_bucket        33588 non-null int64
mileage                  33588 non-null int64
years_licensed_bucket    33588 non-null int64
zip_bucket               33588 non-null float64
monthly_price            33588 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(5)
memory usage: 1.5 MB
```

I am not sure what I should be inputting for the n_classes or if something is wrong with my feature columns.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I resolved this issue. The n_classes argument needs to be greater then the number or classifications your target has. I did not realize the exact amount of classifications in my model. After increasing the n_classes to a higher number then the classifications I have the code executed.

Comment: If we don’t encode the target variable then also we will get above error. So try to encode target variable using `LabelEncoder`. For more details you can refer [this](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/tensorflow-dnnclassifier-4e68df3df00) tutorial. Thanks!