# Assertion failed error in Tensorflow linear regression model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
# IMPORTS
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# IMPORT CSV FILES AS PANDASDB
dfTrain = pd.read_csv('carPriceTrain.csv')
dfEval = pd.read_csv('carPriceEval.csv')

# RENAME COLUMN NAMES
dfTrain = dfTrain.rename(columns={"Gear box type": "gearBoxType"})
dfEval = dfTrain.rename(columns={"Gear box type": "gearBoxType"})
dfTrain = dfTrain.rename(columns={"Leather interior": "leatherInterior"})
dfEval = dfTrain.rename(columns={"Leather interior": "leatherInterior"})

# REMOVE EXTRANEOUS CAR INFORMATION
dfTrain.pop('ID')
dfTrain.pop('Levy')
dfTrain.pop('Category')
dfTrain.pop('Fuel type')
dfTrain.pop('Drive wheels')
dfTrain.pop('leatherInterior')
dfTrain.pop('gearBoxType')
dfTrain.pop('Doors')
dfTrain.pop('Wheel')
dfTrain.pop('Color')
dfTrain.pop('Airbags')

dfEval.pop('ID')
dfEval.pop('Levy')
dfEval.pop('Category')
dfEval.pop('Fuel type')
dfEval.pop('Drive wheels')
dfEval.pop('leatherInterior')
dfEval.pop('gearBoxType')
dfEval.pop('Doors')
dfEval.pop('Wheel')
dfEval.pop('Color')
dfEval.pop('Airbags')

# POP PRICE (PREDICTING VAL)
yTrain = dfTrain.pop('Price')
yEval = dfEval.pop('Price')

# CREATE COLUMNS NAMES
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['Manufacturer', 'Model']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['Prod. year', 'Mileage', 'Cylinders', 'Engine volume']

# FEATURE COLUMNS FOR CATERGORICAL
featureColumns = []
for featureName in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = dfTrain[featureName].unique()
  featureColumns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(featureName, vocabulary))

# FEATURE COLUMNS FOR NUMERIC
for featureName in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    featureColumns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(featureName, dtype=tf.float32))

# CREATING INPUT FN
def makeInputFN(dfData, dfLabel, nEpochs=10, shuffle=True, batchSize=32):
  def inputFN():
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dfData), dfLabel))
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)
    ds = ds.batch(batchSize).repeat(nEpochs)
    return ds
  return inputFN

trainInputFN = makeInputFN(dfTrain, yTrain)
evalInputFN = makeInputFN(dfEval, yEval, nEpochs=1, shuffle=False)

linearEst = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=featureColumns)

linearEst.train(trainInputFN)
result = linearEst.evaluate(evalInputFN)
```

I created a linear regression model using TensorFlow 2.0. I imported a CSV file with data on ID, Price, Levy, Manufacturer, Model, and Prod. year, Category, Leather interior, Fuel type, Engine volume, Mileage, Cylinders, Gearbox type, Drive wheels, Doors, Wheel, Color, Airbags. I popped out rows that I won't be using from these and then continued with the process. I am running into this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /var/folders/kq/823s5gqs0ds7wqckr9sxfcnm0000gn/T/tmp22bryhkx
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py:396: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/ftrl.py:153: calling Constant.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
2022-07-30 15:22:47.534048: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-07-30 15:22:47.549419: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1377, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1360, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1453, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must be <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (head/losses/Cast:0) = ] [[19444][56509][8781]...] [y (head/losses/check_label_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
         [[{{function_node head_losses_check_label_range_assert_less_equal_Assert_AssertGuard_false_667}}{{node Assert}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anirud/CarPricePredictor/main.py", line 75, in <module>
    linearEst.train(trainInputFN)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 360, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1186, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1217, in _train_model_default
    return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1533, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 782, in run
    return self._sess.run(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1311, in run
    return self._sess.run(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1416, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1401, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1469, in run
    outputs = _WrappedSession.run(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1232, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 967, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1190, in _run
    results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1396, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

assertion failed: [Labels must be <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (head/losses/Cast:0) = ] [[19444][56509][8781]...] [y (head/losses/check_label_range/Const:0) = ] [1]
         [[{{node Assert}}]]
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring and don't exactly know where to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at this line:

```
linearEst = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=featureColumns)
```

You should set the argument `n_classes` according to the Tensorflow documentation of the [LinearClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearClassifier).
See the `n_classes` argument says:

> number of label classes. Default is binary classification. Note that
> class labels are integers representing the class index (i.e. values
> from 0 to n_classes-1). For arbitrary label values (e.g. string
> labels), convert to class indices first.

Since the default is binary classification, you should set YOUR number of classes. If I understand correctly you have six classes, so you should have:

```
linearEst = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=featureColumns, n_classes=6)
```

Comment: I added the n_classes=6 line and it still seems to be giving the same error. I think this was a problem in my code but I'm not sure if it was the one giving the error.

Comment: Basically the error is saying that you have a problem with your labels range. Can you do a `.head()` of your training data? It is probable that you have a problem there @Anirud

Comment: i ran `print(dfTrain.head())` and got this data:
```Manufacturer    Model  Prod. year  Engine volume  Mileage  Cylinders
0        LEXUS   RX 450        2010            3.5   186005        6.0
1    CHEVROLET  Equinox        2011            3.0   192000        6.0
2        HONDA      FIT        2006            1.3   200000        4.0
3         FORD   Escape        2011            2.5   168966        4.0
4        HONDA      FIT        2014            1.3    91901        4.0``` I am unsure how to display this properly in mini-Markdown formatting but there are 4 rows from 0-4 and 6 columns.

Comment: I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872962/tensorflow-dnnclassifier-error-labels-must-n-classes-1-condition-x-y). The dataset looks pretty similar to yours and they have the same problem. Try doing what they say in the comments. @Anirud